# How to pass a string from asp.net code behind to local web storage?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, local-storage, code-behind

How do i achieve to pass a string from code-behind c# to local storage by using javascript?

I tried to pass the string over an HiddenField and Session cache, but i had no success by retrieving the string in javascript to store it in the local storage. 
I got an onclick-function in c# to receive a string and write it in the session cache. After that i try to retrieve the string over a function in js where i read the session cache and write it in the local storage. But the result is always empty, except of some tests where i filled the session cache within the page-load function with a static string.

Do anybody suspect the problem in my solution?

I'd appreciate your input.

**Edit:**

First i push Button "btn1" to write myString into the HF and then "btn2" to read it in JS and storage it in the local storage.

HTML-code

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenVar" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="writeInHiddenField" />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClientClick="writeHfInLS()" />

<script>
  function writeHfInLS() { window.localStorage.setItem('key', document.getElementById("hiddenVar").value); }
</script>
```

C#-function in code behind

```
writeInHiddenField() { hiddenVar.Value = myString; }
```

Comment: What did you try? What error do you get?

Comment: I extended my question with some code. There is no error, but the time i call document.getElementById("hiddenVar").value in JS, the value is obviously setted back to the initial value. Like if the sites reloaded or i am working in two different namespaces or something like that.

Comment: Okay, i moved the asp:Buttons out of the UpdatePanel and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hidden field will work.  Assuming web forms, use an asp:Hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="LocalStore" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Then, you can retrieve it via:

```
document.getElementById("LocalStore").value
```

or JQuery:

```
$("#LocalStore").val();
```

Comment: Okay, but the time i call document.getElementById("hiddenVar").value in JS, the value is obviously setted back to the initial value. Like if the sites reloaded or i am working in two different namespaces or something like that. (I extended my question with some code)

Comment: OK, where is your code that sets the value the first time?  Probably in Page Load event, so do you have Not Page.IsPostBack check before you set it?

Comment: The value only get set in the c#-function (writeInHiddenField() { hiddenVar.Value = myString; })

Comment: Did you disable viewstate in the page, or on a parent control?  I've done this approach with no problem.  Also I by "it always resets to the original value", are you verifying that by looking at the HTML that renders and seeing the original value, or by what goes into the local store?

Comment: I didn't disable viewstate. I verified by debugging the page in IE and VS. In the c#-function i see the value set right, but after that i call the JS function with "debugger" and it's empty ""

Comment: When the page posts back and the page rendered, before clicking the button, view source and look at the value for the hidden field to make sure it's not blank.

Comment: FYI i use a sitemaster which includes the JS-file with the function and the HiddenField is added to the asp:Content of the ContentPage.

Comment: I debugged the OnSaveStateComplete-method and the value is still not blank.

Comment: But I would recommend looking in the HTML markup.  If a value is there, the problem is related to something else.  Try putting debugging around the get for value; maybe a value is returned but it's not interpreted correctly, or something else?  Other than that, I don't know of anything else to do.  I've done this with your setup without problem, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you.  Maybe posting more code would help.

Comment: The project based on the Getting started tutorial "WingTip Toys" if that tells u sth. There is a Site.master, Admin Login and so on. I debugged again and the value stays until render. Then even when i call the c#-method again, the constructor of the page starts, the HF is not yet declared and in the page_load method its back again... blank.

Comment: Okay, i moved the asp:Buttons out of the UpdatePanel and now it works.